# How to fix syntax error at or near “psql” in psql shell Windows

Tags: postgresql, psql

```
lecture3-# SELECT * FROM flights;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"
LINE 1: psql
```

This was the code and error. I have added the path link on Environment Variables> System variables> Path edited and added two links underneath

- `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin`
- `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib`

So, if my links are proper why it is showing this

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "psql"

Comment: The statement you have shown us will **not** result in that error. Please copy & paste the **complete** contents of your console window to the question. I assume there is something you left out. This might even be one of the rare cases where a screen shot would be approriate

Comment: I restarted the system now it's working but psql commands aren't working.  ex. (psql -V)

Comment: "arent't working" isn't a valid error message. What exactly is the error you get **now**?

Comment: lecture3=# psql -V
lecture3-#

No error as specific just shows this "lecture3-#  "

Comment: `psql` is a command line program, not a SQL command. If you are already "inside" the `psql` prompt, you can only run SQL commands. Trying to start `psql` from within `psql` obviously doesn't work. If you want to know the Postgres (server) version, use `select version();` if you want to know the version of the `psql` program, use `psql -V` from `cmd.exe`

Answer (score 8):

This happened because you had an unfinished statement from earlier.
So, or you finish it or abort it.

Your psql prompt indicates this.

Statement without ";":

```
<DATABASE>=# <SOME UNFINISHED STATEMENT...>
```

And then a simple query in catalog:

```
<DATABASE>-# SELECT * FROM pg_settings;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "some"
LINE 1: <SOME UNFINISHED STATEMENT...>
        ^
```

Notice that your prompt changed from "=#" to "-#".
The "-#" indicates that there is a statement that isn't finished.

Let's try again:

```
<DATABASE>=# <SOME UNFINISHED STATEMENT...>
```

Abort with `<Ctrl>+<C>`

```
<DATABASE>-# ^C
```

Your prompt is ready again :)

```
<DATABASE>=#
```

Comment: Wow.. indeed by pressing the keys CONTROL + C, to cancel then execute the command again.

Answer (score 0):

When writing in psql the answer is the semicolon!

You can close out your former syntax error(s) and move on by simply using ";"

For example: Here I have accidently pressed "k" and hit enter and then wrote my intended code:

```
mydb=# k
mydb=# SELECT * FROM person
mydb-# WHERE country_of_birth = 'Poland';
```

When I tried to run the code it hit me with the following error.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "k"
LINE 1: k
        ^
```

The solution:

```
mydb=# ;
```

By entering the semicolon, it retroactively closed out the accidental k query with no result and now I am able to re-run my intended code and get an error free result.